# How to compare SOCKADDR_STORAGE address with int[6] mac data?

Tags: c++, macos, sockets, udp, compare

I have problem with comparing MAC address.
My sender address is created as SOCKADDR_STORAGE structure, and the second one is ineger table witch 6 elements.

My question is which parts of SOCKADDR_STORAGE I have to compare with int[6] mac address?

I need this comparison for one if condition.

Comment: please add a  Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and add the correct code formatting tags to your code.

Comment: There are no `SOCKADDR` structs that carry MAC addresses, but there are that carry IP addresses (ie, `sockaddr_in`, `sockaddr_in6`). Why do you think you are able to get a MAC address from a socket API? What are you really trying to compare here?